# How to get the Datatype Info from a type after SOP representation conversion?

Tags: haskell, generics

I'm trying to do some shallow printing on datatype names but I'm not sure how to do this with Generics-SOP.

For the cases where I have a List of my newtype, I can print out what I need fairly easily:

```
class GTypeName f where
  gtypeName :: g f -> String

instance (HasDatatypeInfo a) => GTypeName (SOP I ('[ '[], '[a, [a]] ])) where
  gtypeName _ = "(Array " ++ name ++ ")"
    where
      name = datatypeName $ datatypeInfo (Proxy @ a)
```

As you can see, I'm matching on the List kind and using the inner `a`'s Datatype Info to get the name out. But I don't know how to handle the case where I want to get the actual top level constructor name itself.

In GHC Generics I did the following:

```
instance (GTypeName f) => GTypeName (D1 m f) where -- peer inside
  gtypeName _ = gtypeName (Proxy @ f)

-- go into the Cons constructed type
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (GTypeName f) => GTypeName (C1 ('MetaCons ":" g s) f) where
  gtypeName _ = gtypeName (Proxy @ f)

-- return the constructor name here
instance (KnownSymbol n) => GTypeName (C1 ('MetaCons n g s) f) where
  gtypeName _ = symbolVal (Proxy @ n)

-- take the left side, as this is the result of a type product from Cons
instance (GTypeName a) => GTypeName (a :*: b) where
  gtypeName _ =
    gtypeName (Proxy @ a)

-- match on array and take it out here
instance (GTypeName b) => GTypeName ((C1 ('MetaCons "[]" g s) f) :+: b) where
  gtypeName _ = "(Array " ++ gtypeName (Proxy @ b) ++ ")"
```

This is ultimately used with a newtype and some data types like so:

```
newtype Status = Status Text

newtype OpenRequest = OpenRequest
  { path :: Path
  }

data Route req res = Route
  { method :: Method
  , url :: Url
  }

open :: Route OpenRequest Success
open = Route {method = POST, url = Url "/api/open"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the top-level constructor name of a value using generics-sop as follows:

```
constructor ::
  forall a .
  (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a) => a -> String
constructor a =
  hcollapse $
  hzipWith
    (\ con _args -> K (constructorName con))
    (constructorInfo (datatypeInfo (Proxy @a)))
    (unSOP $ from a)
```

Here, `constructorInfo ...` gives you a product containing all constructor names of the datatype in question. the `hzipWith` call then selects the constructor that the given value `a` belongs to.

Examples:

```
GHCi> constructor True
"True"
GHCi> constructor (Just 3)
"Just"
GHCi> constructor [1,2,3]
":"
```

Unfortunately, it's not entirely clear to me what you want to do with list types, so I cannot show how to combine this with the code you already have.

Comment: Sorry, realized that the question in my title is wholly different from the content of the body, but then I found that since I only call my method with data types, I could get away with less hacky solutions. Thanks! I have my repo here where I'm now trying to convert the ExtractFields instances to SOP here: https://github.com/justinwoo/godawful-purescript-codegen-demo